# Modular @Configuration/@Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, configuration, modularity

I'm making a MicroServices based project so I have more the one Spring Boot projects in my workspace. I need to configure restOperations in some of then but I want to configure once for all the project that needs. So I'm trying to add my `@Configuration` class to a jar and import in each MS projects.

The problem is, when I execute the MS project in my server, I receive this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field restOperations in com.epavanellio.base.business.controller.BusinessController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' in your configuration.
```

Here I have my Rest configuration class:

```
package com.epavanellio.base.restConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

//@Component
@Configuration
public class SimpleRestConfiguration {
    
    final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
            .build();
    
    @Bean
    public RestOperations createRestTemplate(final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory){
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory createHttpRequestFactory (@Value("${rest.connect.timeout}") final int connectTimeout,
            @Value("${rest.read.timeout}") final int readTimeout) {
        
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        
        return clientHttpRequestFactory;
    }
    
}
```

I imported the `.jar (dpdc-rest)` with has the `SimpleRestConfiguration` class in my MS project POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.epavanellio.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>ms-manager-business</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ms-manager-business</name>
    <description>Validate business logic. A microservice based project. </description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epavanellio.base</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epavanellio.base</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpdc-rest</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epavanellio.base</groupId>
            <artifactId>dpdc-custom-exception-handler</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ms-manager-business</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and in my MS application class is like this:

```
package com.epavanellio.base.business;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import com.epavanellio.base.restConfig.SimpleRestConfiguration;


//@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.epavanellio.base", "com.epavanellio.base.restConfig"})
//@Import(SimpleRestConfiguration.class)
//@ComponentScan({"com.epavanellio.base", "com.epavanellio.base.restConfig"})
@ComponentScan("com.epavanellio.base")
@EntityScan("com.epavanellio.base.domain")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessApplication.class, args);
    }
    
     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(BusinessApplication.class);
     }
}
```

as you can see commented, I already tried to my make my runtime "see" my configuration class in diffrent ways:
First I tried to add `(scanBasePackages={"com.epavanellio.base", "com.epavanellio.base.restConfig"})` after my annotation `@SpringBootApplication`, but the same error occurs. Then I tried to add specifically the `SimpleRestConfiguration` class package to the `@ComponentScan` annotation(for this, I uncommented the `@Component` annotation in `SimpleRestConfiguration` class), but the same error occurs. At least I tried to use `@Import`, but in this case I receive the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/epavanellio/base/restConfig/SimpleRestConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

does any one know how can I make my application class to "see" my
`@Configuration` class?

Comment: Since you got two different projects for this, dependency project must be built 1st with `mvn install` or `mvn clean install` to add the artifacts to local repository. Then only those changes are available on dependent project. Whenever you change your `dpdc-rest` project, make sure to follow up the build order unless this is a maven module project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Maven, for some reason maven was no recognizing my jar.

so I made a new dependency project, with a new name but same same SimpleRestConfiguration class. I imported the new .Jar to my MS and then works fine.

My application become like this:

```
@ComponentScan("com.epavanellio.base")
@EntityScan("com.epavanellio.base.domain")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserApplication.class, args);
    }
    
     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(UserApplication.class);
     }
}
```